# Why node.js file uploading api is keeps on pending infinitely?

Tags: node.js, express

In my `node.js` `api` i have an api `route` for `file uploading` like this

route.js

```
const { saveFilesToFolder } = require('../helpers/fileuploadHelper');

router.post('/upload-files', saveFilesToFolder, catchAsyncErrors(UploadFiles));
```

helper.js

```
const saveFilesToFolder = async(req, res, next) => {

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: imageFilter,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10
    }
}).any();

upload(req, res, (err) => {
    const wasValidRequest = checkAllowedFiles(req);

    if (wasValidRequest.status === false) {
        return res.send({
            status: false,
            message: wasValidRequest.message,
            response: null
        })
    }

    // counter = 0
    if (err) {
        console.log(`Error uploading files, ${err.message}`)
        return res.send({
            status: false,
            message: `Error occurred while uploading files, ${err.message}`,
            response: null
        })
    }

    // WHEN FILE UPLOADING IS DONE NOW PASSING THE REQUEST
    next();
 });
};


const storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: async (req, file, cb) => {
    let path = getFileStoragePath(req, file);
    console.log(`path to create ${path}`)
    checkDirectory(path, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Error occured if checkDirectory ${err.message}`)
            cb(err, null)
        } else {
            cb(null, path);
        }
    });
},
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    let dateNow = Date()
    cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${dateformat(dateNow, 'dddd_mmmm_dS_yyyy_h_MM_ss_TT')}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
  }
});



  let checkDirectory = async(path, callback) => {
  if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }
        callback(null);
    });
  } else {
    callback(null);
 }
};
```

But the problem is that when i try to call this api form front-end so it receives all the files which are sending from front-end and it all shows when i run in through debugger but it disappears after `checkDirectory` calling line inside `destination` of `multer.diskStorage`. I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging each piece of above code i came to know that `node.js` has no longer `callback` available for `fs.mkdirSync()` so that's why callback part was not executing. I fixed it by replacing `fs.mkdirSync()` to `fs.mkdir()` which has `callback`.